# Proxying with Apache + SSL to JBoss with AJP - loosing data.

Tags: apache, ssl, jboss, proxy, ajp

I have Apache2.2 with SSL and JBoss 4.2.1 with JavaWeb-application.
Apache works as proxy-server to transportation data to/from JBoss with AJP-protocol.

The problem is when Apache gets data from client with HTTPS and send them to JBoss, JBoss gets SOME empty fields (i.e. some fields is "").
When I using

> `http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapp/`...

it works ok!

Is anybody had this problem before?

Thanks for response!

My Apache2 settings:

```
<VirtualHost <ip_address>:443>
ServerAdmin admin@domain
ServerName <domain>

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
    SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH

SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN on
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire on

DocumentRoot /var/www/jboss.local
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/jboss.local>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^domain$  domain/
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/jboss.local/error.log
LogLevel warn
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/jboss.local/access.log combined

    <Location /myapp/>
       Order Deny,Allow
       Allow from all
       RequestHeader    unset  Accept-Encoding
       ProxyHTMLURLMap      /      /myapp/
       ProxyHTMLURLMap      /myapp  /myapp
       ProxyPass        ajp://`127.0.0.1`/myapp/
       ProxyPassReverse     ajp://`127.0.0.1`/myapp/
       RequestHeader    unset  Accept-Encoding
    </Location>
```